# How to pass an onClick to parent in React

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

I have a React component called beercard which populates an item for me and adds a like button, here's the Beercard file:

```
function Beercard(props) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const changeLike = () => {
    setActive(!active)
  }

  return (
    <BeerCard>
      <Content>
        <Lockup text={props.description} tag="h3" title={props.title}/>
      </Content>
      <ImagContainer>
        <Like liked={active}  />
        <Image url={props.image}/>
      </ImagContainer>
    </BeerCard>
  )
}
```

Then I have the Like component, which I will use to handle the onClick:

```
const Icon = styled.svg`
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  stroke:  white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: ${props => props.liked ? 'white' : 'transparent'};
`


const like = (props) => {
  return (
    <LikeButton onClick={props.action}>
      <Icon liked={props.liked}>
        <path 
          id="heart-icon" 
          d="M16,28.261c0,0-14-7.926-14-17.046c0-9.356,13.159-10.399,14-0.454c1.011-9.938,14-8.903,14,0.454
    C30,20.335,16,28.261,16,28.261z"
        />
      </Icon>
    </LikeButton>
  )
}
```

It all works fine ie with the css for filled and unfilled, then if I set the state to true in the beercard file it sets the heart to active/fills it. However the onClick function is not doing anything and I'm not sure how to communicate between the two files to add this event. It's a simple on/off toggle with true and false but I don't know how to handle the event, can somebody see what I need to do?

Comment: You are using a prop that does not exists in your Like component. `<Like liked={active}  />` You must pass it and it should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to pass along the desired function as a property to the Like component. You're actually 90% there, but you're calling `props.action` in `onClick`, but passing nothing to the action property.
Since you already have everything, you can change the line where you use your Like component to:

`<Like liked={active} action={changeLike} />`